# How to partition SD card in HTC One X?

Tags: external-sd, file-system, htc-one-x, partitions

I was trying to create `ext2`/`ext3`/`ext4` partitions on the SD card. I tried ClockworkMod recovery and it didn't work. Nothing seems to have happened.

I also tried using MiniTool and that also failed. I tried both Disk Utility and GParted in Ubuntu and it still didn't work. For MiniTool, Disk Utility, and GParted, after I finished partitioning the partitions showed up on the computer OK, but when USB's disconnected the One X says that the SD card's corrupted.

Has anybody done this? Or is there some other way to solve this?

Or maybe it's not possible because the SD card is built-in?

Thanks!

---

After some more playing around, it seems that the problem might be something related to a partition table.

When there's no partition table, it works fine, but after I add a partition table it seems that the phone can't recognize the SD card anymore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think [this post](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?p=29891113#post29891113) provides some information about it. It also seems to be consistent with what I've tried.

Instead of partitioning the SD card, mounting an `.img` with a `ext4` filesystem is a simple workaround.