# creating a pseudo sd card by partitioning the main drive of an android phone

Tags: cyanogenmod, nexus-4, htc-one-x, partitions, internal-sd

It seems like it's possible to mount the SD card of rooted android phone on a PC while the phone is connected to the PC via USB. This would be great for me because I want to keep essential files saved on my phone, edit them from the PC when I need to and bring them with me wherever I go. Unfortunately, the phones I want the most (nexus 4, HTC one, HTC one x with 64gb) don't have SD cards. Is it possible (on a rooted phone with cyanogenmod) to partition the "HD" on a phone without an SD card and then use that partition as described above? (The format of the partition is not very important to me.)

Will the solution suggested here[1] make it possible to mount the .img file on the PC while the phone is connected via USB?

[1] https://android.stackexchange.com/a/27146/29982

Comment: In short: no (technically yes, but you need your own kernel). Longer answer: Android 4.x doesn't officially support exporting the sdcard via USB mass storage any more (and with good cause). The underlying Linux kernel doesn't include the necessary driver to export this any more. So you would need to compile your own with that functionality included. Background: USB mass storage opens a can of worms: you need to use a separate partition with the ancient FAT32 file system (for compatibility), access to the card is exclusive (phone *or* PC at a time), and so on.

Comment: So this means (I'm not familiar with the terminology) no access to either the "internal" or sd-card storage on a PC with a phone connected via USB? (I assume you noticed I wrote "rooted phone with cyanogenmod".)

Comment: Actually, for me exclusive access is a plus. I'm uncomfortable with syncing because it's hard to be absolutely certain nothing will go wrong, and to notice if it does.

Comment: Right. This means only the new MTP mode will work but not USB thumb drive mode. Exclusive is a big minus, because apps need to deal with the then inaccessible sdcard which is connected+mounted on the PC. SwiftKey keyboard doesn't fully work if the prediction data on the sdcard is inaccessible for example.

Comment: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/26288/how-can-i-use-my-galaxy-nexus-as-an-external-usb-storage-drive and also http://www.androidpolice.com/2011/11/18/impromptu-qa-session-with-android-engineer-dan-morrill-brings-to-light-reasons-behind-galaxy-nexus-lack-of-usb-mass-storage/